# No se ven datos de formulario

Tags: php, html, sql

Tengo un codigo realizado en php, html y mysql. El mismo debe traer datos de la BD.
Pero en algun lado esta el error dado que no me trae los datos, pero no me arroja ningun mensaje de error.
Actualizar los actualiza bien, pero no los muestra.

```html
   <head>

<?php include ("header.php")?>

<?php
session_start();

include "conexion.php";

$result = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM jugadores");
?>

<title>BD - Jugadores</title>
    
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link href="css/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link href="css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
    <br>

    <div class="row table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Apellido</th>
    <th>Mail</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))  {}?>
    </tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["nombre"]; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row["apellido"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["mail"]; ?></td> 
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
```

Esto tengo en donde me deberia mostar el listado cargado en SQL.
Ahora no me muestra nada para poder tener un boton eliminar por cada uno o un select.

```
<?php
    $nombre_user = $_POST["nombre"];
    $apellido_user = $_POST["apellido"];
    $mail_user = $_POST["mail"];
    echo $nombre_user." ".$apellido_user." ".$mail_user;
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "plantilla") or exit ("No se pudo conectar");

    mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO jugadores (nombre,apellido,mail) VALUES ('$nombre_user','$apellido_user','$mail_user')");


    mysqli_close($conexion);
    echo "YA GRABE";
    ?>
```

Este se llama carga_usuario.php

Comment: No es que te encuentres perdido, es que no has hecho nada. Por otro lado, repasa como se construye un HTML correctamente pues has puesto `<title>` y `<link>` en el cuerpo del documento cuando tienen que ir en la etiqueta `<head>`.  Son demasiados fallos para poderte hacer el ejercicio por ti, lo siento, esta pregunta no cumple con lo indicado en [ask] y podrá ser cerrada por ese motivo.

Comment: Mil disculpas, ya lo modifique.

Comment: Pues recorre el resultado del SELECT y pinta una fila por cada fila de la consulta. A eso le puedes añadir el elemento HTML que desees y puedes hacer que se envíe una petición al servidor con un identificador único de ese jugador (el email? apellido con email? Los tres campos?) para llamar una consulta DELETE FROM jugadores

Comment: movería `session_start();` al inicio, luego transforma `}?></tbody>` en `<?php }?></tbody>` y muevelo justo antes de `</table>`

Answer (score 0):

revise tu código y tiene varias inconsistencias, como dicen en los comentarios trata de revisar bien la estructura, te hice unos archivos, trata de replicarlos y entender esta estructura, los pongo en captura y el código al final

1- "conexion.php" para poner los datos de tu servidor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.- "insertar.php" aqui es para insertar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3.- "eliminar.php"  aqui para eliminar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4.- "index.php" aqui la pagina que se visualizara todo, y manda a llamar a las demas

```html
<?php include("conexion.php");
$con = conectar();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM jugadores";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <!--     estilos bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!--     estilos bootstrap -->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!--     Tabla para ingresar -->
            <div class="col col-sm-2">
                <h1>ingresar Usuario</h1>
                <form action="insertar.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="id" id="id" placeholder="id">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="nombre">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="apellido" id="apellido" placeholder="apellido">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control mb-3" name="mail" id="mail" placeholder="mail">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col md-8">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead class="table-success table-striped">
                        <tr>
                            <th>id del usuario</th>
                            <th>nombre</th>
                            <th>apellido</th>
                            <th>mail</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <!--     tabla que muestra los registros -->
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                        ?>
                            <tr>
                                <th><?php echo $row['id'] ?></th>
                                <th><?php echo $row['nombre'] ?></th>
                                <th><?php echo $row['apellido'] ?></th>
                                <th><?php echo $row['mail'] ?></th>
                                <th><a href="editar.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-info">Editar</a></th>
                                <th><a href="eliminar.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a></th>
                            </tr>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

inserto los demas codigos

```html
<!--     conexion   -->

<?php function conectar(){

    $host = "localhost";
    $user ="root";  /*   tu usuario del server */
    $pass ="";  /*   tu contraseña del server */
    $bd ="prueba";  /*   tu base de datos del server */
    $con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    mysqli_select_db($con,$bd);
    return $con;
}
?>
<!--     conexion   -->

<!--     delete   -->


<?php 
include("conexion.php");
$con=conectar();
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql= "DELETE FROM jugadores WHERE id = '$id'";
$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if ($query) {
    header('location: index.php'); 
    exit();
    


    }
    else {

    }
?>
<!--     delete   -->


<!--     insertar   -->
<?php 
include("conexion.php");
$con=conectar();

    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido=$_POST['apellido'];
    $mail=$_POST['mail'];

$sql= "INSERT INTO jugadores VALUES(
    '$id', 
    '$nombre', 
    '$apellido', 
    '$mail')";

$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if ($query) {
    header('location: index.php'); 
    exit();
    
    }
    else {

    }

?>

<!--     insertar   -->
```

este es el resultado que te deberia salir, teniendo en cuenta tus datos de la tabla jugadores la mia es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el resultado seria

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en conclusión esto es un crud, prueba ver algunos videos de como hacer un crud , te servirá igual para lo que pides y modificarlo y usarlo para futuros proyectos, tenia uno por ahí. solo lo adapte para que te dieras una idea, te dejo de tarea hacer el update , saludos!!

Comment: Muchisimas gracias de vedad! me ayudo mucho a entender el proceso, me gusto el diseño, solo me falta agregarle que los campos sean obligatorios y editar mas la BD. GRACIAS!

Comment: asi se empieza poco a poco solo que le entiendas el por que , y estructures bien todo, ya eso que pides puede ser con un required <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="nombre" required> , saludos